# python populating array using while loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, while-loop

All I am trying to do is populate an array with numbers in order. So, array[0][0] = 0, array[0][1]=1, etc. Why is this not working?  I cannot figure it out.

```
def populateArray(ar):
    count = 0
    i=0
    j=0
    while (i<len(ar)):
        while (j<len(ar[i])):
            ar[i][j] = count
            count = count + 1
            j=j+1
        j=0
        i=i+1
    return ar

numColumns = input('how many columns?')
numRows = input('how many rows?')
arr = [[0]*int(numColumns)]*int(numRows)
arr=populateArray(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: *How* is this "not working"? This is important information and should be part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

when you initiate your `arr` variable, you are multiplying a list of lists with a number, this results in a "mess" because what you actually do it is to multiply only the reference of the first list (from your list of lists), so actually you have in your `arr` only one list and a bunch of reference to that list, to fix this you can do:

```
arr = [[0] * int(numColumns) for _ in range(int(numRows))]
```

or:

```
arr = [[0 for _ in range(int(numColumns))] for _ in range(int(numRows))]
```

after changing this in your code, for `numRows = 3` and `numColumns = 4` you get:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: thank you for the info, this is exactly what i needed to know.  So it wasn't the while loop that was the problem, just how i initialized my array (arr variable).  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
numColumns = input('how many columns?') 
numRows = input('how many rows?') 
arr = [[i+j for i in range(int(numRows))] for j in range(int(numColumns))] 
arr=populateArray(arr) 
print(arr)
```

The problem with your code is that you append same array to the main array multiple times, like this `[l, l, l]` and `l` is a list.

So when ever you change an elemenet of `l` it will change all of `l`s in your list.

So, your code works fine but each time you change another list, all of previous list will be effected.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this syntax to create multi dimensional array

```
arr = [[0]*int(numColumns)]*int(numRows)
```

the reference of same element is created  many times , so if you assign a value to one of them then you are basically changing all the elements because they all reference to the same data.
for ex :

```
arr = [[0]*int(numColumns)]*int(numRows)
arr[0][1]=2
print(arr)
```

output

```
[[0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2]]
```

I only changed one element and this is the result . 
you should use :

```
arr = [[0 for i in range(int(numColumns))] for j in range(int(numRows))]
arr[0][1]=2
print(arr)
```

output :

```
[[0, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for creating the structure, followed by using [numpy.tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) for converting it to a python list

```
import numpy as np
numColumns = int(input('how many columns?')) 
numRows = int(input('how many rows?') )
arr = np.arange(numRows*numColumns).reshape(numRows, numColumns).tolist()
print(arr)
```